# Sending a POST request from AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, object, post

In the Angular `service` code I have:

```
App.factory('Set', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:80/');
  }]);
```

And this is controllers code:

```
data.push({
    item: [{
        "time": time,
        "value": valueParsed
    }]
});

Set.save({
    param1: time
    }, {
    data: data
    }).$promise.then(function(res) { 
});
```

However the POST request doesn't go through. Am I sending the wrong object with wrong type?

Comment: Are you trying to post to back end mongodb server? Are you using mongoose schemas?

Comment: @mjwrazor no. I'm sending a POST to a sample service running on Port 80.

Comment: "request doesn't go through" is too vague. What is the content of the error message? What is the response status code?

Comment: @JoelCDoyle no response in network element of console.log. Nothing. it's waiting for response.

Comment: In the curl you are sending an object; In the $resource save method, you are sending an array.  The `save` method of a $resource expects an object, not an array. Also there is no need to stringify the object, the $resource will do that because the $http service automatically does that.